# Can I run this monitor?

Tags: display, resolution, lcd, integrated-graphics

I am upto buying new monitor for my desktop. Here are some specs.and you please help me choose a better one (an which one will work)?

Graphics property of system :

Intel(R) 82845G Graphics Controller

Memory  64 MB

Memory type 2

Driver version  6.13.01.3317

Monitors i think will be good is.

Monitor  : http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=viewsonic+22&cid=10503070423897692907&ei=MKj_S5OGCpOgjgSghsX2CA&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA&os=tech-specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to be able to find anything which can confirm that the graphics card can run at the native resolution of 1920 x 1080.  You will be able to connect to the monitor, but if you can't run at the native resolution then it will not be the sharpest picture possible.

If you check in your display properties control panel and see what the maximum resolution for that card is.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is the resolution - 1920 x 1080.

Can your graphics chip go that high?

It's difficult to check with your current setup as Windows Display Properties limits the choices to what the current monitor can support.

Comment: yeh right  :( .You know anyway i can check the highest res ?
Some software or soemthing

Comment: @akshay - I'd do a Google search for "Intel 82845G resolution" (or something similar